# Have only the boot partition on one drive

Tags: system-installation

Is it possible for me to buy a small hard drive, as the boot SSD, and then have the boot partition on that drive, while installing stuff like `/etc`, `/var`, `/home` to the bigger drive?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You'd put Ubuntu on the SSD, and /home and swap on the HDD. My pure SSD system boots in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. However it does not make any sense to me. it's better to store a path like `/` on your fast hard drive and paths like `/home` or `/var` on a separate hard drive with more capacity.

---

When system is booting BIOS looks for a bootable device, it does not matter which hard drive it is, a small section of its first sector (boot sector) contains a specific code (boot loader binary code) which knows where `/boot` is located and thus does the job.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is for a boot drive setup, where I can have a very small drive, which should make the system boot up quicker, and having the  post boot files on the slower drive

Comment: Fair enough ...